# Using parent() function and overriding parent's children block

Tags: twig

How can I use {{ parent() }} and override one of its children blocks, I found some solution but it looks wrong, here is an example that may be explain the issue:

**index.html.twig:**

```
{% block wrapper %}
    <h1>title</h1>
    {% block one %}<p>Content of block one</p>{% endblock one %}
    {% block two %}<p>Content of block one</p>{% endblock two %}
{% endblock wrapper %}
```

**new_index.html.twig:**

```
{% extends 'index.html.twig' %}
{% block wrapper %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% block two %}<p>NEW content of block two</p>{% endblock two %}
{% endblock wrapper %}
```

But I see the content of block two twice (and it looks logical). How can I update the code to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, solution is simple, just write block two outside the wrapper block, there is no hierarchy for blocks :)

**new_index.html.twig:**

```
{% extends 'index.html.twig' %}
{% block wrapper %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock wrapper %}
{% block two %}<p>NEW content of block two</p>{% endblock two %}
```