# Twig template archive-events extends archive extends base

Tags: inheritance, twig

Is it possible to create extend chain of more than one inheritance, like so:

**archive-events.twig** extends **archive.twig**
**archive.twig** extends **base.twig**

Or is the extend chain also considered as multiple inheritance?

Also is it possible to override a sub block, like so:

**archive.twig**
--block content
----block meta

**archive-events.twig**
----block meta
...

This is the archive-events.twig:

```
{# archive-events.twig #}
{% extends "archive.twig" %}
{% block content %}

    {{ parent() }}

    {% block articles %}  
        {% for post in posts %}
            {% include "article-event.twig" %}
        {% endfor %}                      
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

archive.twig:

```
{# archive.twig #}
{% extends "base.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    <!-- start:article-archive -->
        <section class="section layout context--post-list context--event">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <header>
                        {% block header %}
                        <h1 class="title">{{ title }}</h1>
                        {% endblock %}
                    </header>

                    <div class="filter">
                        {% block archive_filter %}                                           

                        {% endblock %}
                    </div>

                    <div class="articles">

                        {% block articles %}  

                        {% endblock %}

                    </div><!-- .articles -->
                </div><!-- .container -->
            </div><!-- .wrapper -->
        </section>
        <!-- end:article-archive -->
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible and very useful.

If you use inherited templates, remember about function `{{ parent() }}` placed in block. Another useful function is `{% include %}`.

More info in [official doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is great.<br/>

2nd answer: If I use {{ parent() }} it does display correctly with the overrided sub block, but then it displays the sub block one more time after the whole parent() content. Any way around it?

I'll edit the main question with the template example.

Comment: For anyone looking for the same thing, here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770567/using-parent-function-and-overriding-parents-children-block/34770789
It seems that blocks don't need to follow hierarchy.